# How to adjust \cftchapnumwidth dynamically?

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation, tocloft

I'm using `tocloft` package to format Table of Contents.

The problem is reproduced in the following minimal working example. The indentation level of Appendix A is incorrect. But the command `\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{30mm}` doesn't work for the second time.

[image]

Here is the text version of the picture:

---

```
 Contents

 Chapter 1. My chapter name bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla         2

 Appendix A:  My appendix name bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla         3
            ^ $

 ^ - incorrect indentation level (25 mm)
 $ - correct indentation level (30 mm)
```

---

This picture was produces by the following code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany,oneside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{25mm} %25mm have been chosen manually

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Chapter 1. My chapter name bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 1. My chapter name bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla}

Chapter text.

\appendix

\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{30mm}  %This command doesn't work!

\chapter*{Appendix A: My appendix name bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix A: My appendix name bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla}

Appendix Text.

\end{document}
```

I have no idea how to patch the code.

Comment: `\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{30mm}` has to go before `\tableofcontents`, it is there it is used not within the text itself. Regarding your manual adding `Chapter`, the `memoir` class can do this automatically plus `memoir` has the `tocloft` features build in.

Comment: Before addressing the ToC issue, I have a question: it's not clear to me why you use `\chapter*` and `\addcontentsline`; why don't you simply use `\chapter`?

Comment: @Gonzalo, actually it's a model example. In the real file I start each appendix with \Appendix command described in the preamble. \Appendix calls: \chapter*{#1} and \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix \thechapter: #1}. Since I'm new to latex, I'm happy that it works :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the line after `\appendix` into

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{30mm}}
```

after `\appendix`, so that the directive will be issued at the correct time, when typesetting the table of contents.