# Center part title in TOC

Tags: classicthesis, parts

i would like to center the part title in the table of contents (TOC) of my thesis. Based on an answer of egreg, i was able to at least modify the space between part number and part title in the TOC.
However, I cannot set this length individually for each \part (i try it in the MWE below, but as can be seen in the result, it does not work).

```
\documentclass[dottedtoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[parts]{classicthesis} 
%custom space between number and text in toc: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140053/38853
\makeatletter
\def\ttl@tocpart{% %magic code, don't ask
  \def\ttl@a{\protect\numberline{\thepart}\@gobble{}}}
\setlength{\cftpartnumwidth}{100px}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents 
\part{P1}
\chapter{Ch1}
\setlength{\cftpartnumwidth}{150px}
\part{P2}
\chapter{Ch2}
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

Other solutions are welcome as well!
(I am aware of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210676/38853, however, I don't see how to put the part number on the left and the page number on the right, as in the picture)

Comment: You have to write the setting of the length to the toc-file.

Comment: Related: [Align section number with bottom line of title in TOC with tocloft](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/232741), [Space between conclusion and appendices in ToC](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/156271), [How to adjust \cftchapnumwidth dynamically?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47194)

Comment: @Johannes_B, this (combined with http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47194) answers my question, thank you! Is there also a possibility to center the part titles (in TOC) automatically?

Comment: I am not a `titletoc` user, so i don't know. Using `titletoc` with KOMA-script is discouraged by the way, as is using `titlesec`. Please, ask that as a new question to better sort our archive. If you make the question independent of using `classicthesis`, even better. More possible solutions for others to find.

Comment: You can self-answer this one right here. Closing as duplicate is hard in that case.

Comment: I'll do, but still wait for a while as this is somewhat hacky right now (change value for each part entry) - maybe a more elegant solution for the centering the part title comes up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Johannes_B's comments my hacky solution can be completed:

```
\documentclass[dottedtoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[parts]{classicthesis} 
%custom space between number and text in toc: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140053/38853
\makeatletter
\def\ttl@tocpart{% %magic code, don't ask
  \def\ttl@a{\protect\numberline{\thepart}\@gobble{}}}
\setlength{\cftpartnumwidth}{100px}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents 
\part{P1}
\chapter{Ch1}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setlength{\cftpartnumwidth}{150px}}
\part{P2}
\chapter{Ch2}
\end{document}
```

yields

[image]

Still, more comfortable solutions for centering the title are welcome. :)